# Why can we not access elements of a tuple by index?

Tags: c++, stl

```
tuple <int, string, int> x=make_tuple(1, "anukul", 100);
cout << x[0];       //1
cout << get<0>(x);  //2
```

2 works. 1 does not.

Why is it so?

From Lounge C++ I learnt that it is probably because the compiler does not know what data type is stored at that index.
But it did not make much sense to me as the compiler could just look up the declaration of that tuple and determine  the data type or do whatever else is done while accessing other data structures' elements by index.

Comment: BTW, imho the *correct* pattern would have been `x.0`

Comment: @PaoloM except function names cannot start with a number.

Comment: duplicate? that's a long stretch!

Comment: @UmNyobe Hmmm, I don't know why Community did that? But the reason this can't be done is *very* well documented in the other question's answers.

Comment: @TartanLlama I was meaning that an `std::tuple` is much more an unnamed struct than an array of something

Comment: Both are difficult to read if the tuple declaration isn't near the read. What's 0????

Comment: @user997112 True.. probably applies to any variable in general. I personally use IDE magic. 

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Because [] is an operator (named `operator[]`), thus a member function, and is called at run-time.

Whereas getting the tuple item is a template mechanism, it must be resolved at compile time. Which means this can be only done with the <> templating syntax.

To better understand, a tuple may store different types. A template function may return different types depending on the index passed, as this is resolved at compile time.
The operator[] must return a unique type, whatever the value of the passed parameter is. Thus the tuple functionality is not achievable.

`get<0>(x)` and `get<1>(x)` are two different functions generated at compile time, and return different types. The compiler generates in fact two functions which will be mangled to something like

```
int get_tuple_int_string_int_0(x)
```

and

```
string get_tuple_int_string_int_1(x)
```

Answer (score 17):

The other answers here address the issue of why this isn't possible to implement, but it's also worth asking the question of whether it *should* be possible. (The answer is no.)

The subscript operator `[]` is semantically supposed to indicate dynamically-resolved access to a element of a collection, such as an array or a list (of any implementation). The access pattern generally implies certain things: the number of elements probably isn't known to the surrounding code, which element is being accessed will probably vary at runtime, and the elements are all of the same observable type (thus, to the calling code, interchangeable).

Thing is, a tuple isn't (that kind of) a collection. It's actually an anonymous `struct`, and its elements aren't interchangeable slots at all - semantically, they are regular fields. What's probably throwing you off is that they happen to be labelled with numbers, but that's really just an anonymous naming pattern - analogous to accessing the elements as `x._0`, `x._1`, etc. (The fact you can compute the field names *at compile-time* is a coincidental bonus enabled by C++'s type system, and is not fundamentally related to what a tuple is; tuples, and this answer, are not really specific to C++.)

So it doesn't support `operator[]` for the same reason that plain old structs don't support `operator[]`: there's no semantically-valid use for it in this context. Structures have a fixed set of fields that aren't interchangeable or dynamically computable, and since the tuple *is* a structure, not a collection, it follows the same rule. Its field names just look different.

Comment: Type-theoretically, tuples and records are both product types, with the only difference being that a record's components are labeled, and a tuple's aren't. So, yes, a tuple is pretty much exactly the same as a `struct` (which is how C++ spells "record") with anonymous fields.

Answer (score 6):

It can be supported, it just needs to take a compile-time index. Since parameters of a function cannot be made `constexpr`, we need to wrap the index within a type and pass that instead. (e.g. `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>`.

The following is an extension of `std::tuple` that supports `operator[]`.

```
template <typename... Ts>
class tuple : public std::tuple<Ts...> {
  public:
  using std::tuple<Ts...>::tuple;

  template <std::size_t N>
  decltype(auto) operator[](std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>) {
    return std::get<N>(*this);
  }
};
```

It would be used like so:

```
tuple<int, std::string> x(42, "hello");
std::cout << x[std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{}] << std::endl;
// prints: 42
```

To mitigate the `std::integral_constant` crazy, we can use variable template:

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> ic;
```

With this, we can say:

```
std::cout << x[ic<1>] << std::endl;  // prints: hello
```

So it could be done. One guess as to why this is currently not available is because features such as `std::integral_constant` and variable templates may not have existed at the time `std::tuple` was introduced. As to why it doesn't exist even though those features exist, I would guess it's because no one have yet to proposed it.

Comment: Variable templates definitely didn't exist then, and as your example shows, the syntax is pretty gross without them (although we could have done it with the placeholders from `std::bind`, i.e. `x[_1]`, if they weren't one-based indices rather than zero-based!). I totally agree the reason we don't have it is the usual answer to "why isn't this in the standard?!" ... nobody proposed it. Maybe you should :)

Comment: Why is integer constant needed? Wouldnt consexpr be enough?

Answer (score 5):

It's not very clean supporting `operator[]` given you can't vary the static return type to match the accessed element.  If the Standard Library had incorporated something like `boost::any` or `boost::variant`, it would make more sense.

Put another way, if you write something like:

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
int x = x[n];
```

Then what should it do if `n` doesn't address an `int` member of the `tuple`?  To even support checking you'd need to store some manner of RunTime Type Information for `tuple`s, which is extra overhead in the executable/memory.

Comment: can we not use `auto` (C++ 14) ?

Comment: @AnukulSangwan: no - `auto` must be able to work out a specific type at compile time, so it knows how much memory to reserve for the object, which destructor to call etc..

Answer (score 2):

Containers that support the *subscript operator* (i.e., `operator[]`) like `std::vector` or `std::array` are collections of ***homogenous*** values. Whatever the index provided to the subscript operator is, the value to return is always of the same type. Therefore, those containers can define a member function with the following declaration:

```
T& operator[](int);
```

Where `T` is the type of *every element in the collection*.

On the other hand, an `std::tupe` is a collection of ***heterogeneous*** values. The return value of a hypothetical subscript operator for `std::tuple` needs to vary with the index. Therefore, its return type depends on the index.

In the declaration of the `operator[]` given above, the index is provided as a function argument and therefore may be determined at run time. However, the return type of the function is something that needs to be determined at compile time, not at run time.

Since the return type of such a function depends on the index but must be determined at compile-time, the solution is to define instead a function *template* that accepts the index as a *(non-type) template parameter*. This way, the index is provided as a compile-time constant and the return type is able to change with the index:

```
template<std::size_t I, class... Types>
typename std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...>>::type& get(tuple<Types...>&) noexcept;
```

As you can see, `std::get`'s return type depends on the index, `I`:

```
std::tuple_element<I, tuple<Types...>>::type&
```

Answer (score 1):

Because tuple has no operator *"bracket"*.
Why is it so? You cannot resolve templates based only on the return value. You cannot write

```
template<typename T>
T tuple::operator [](size_t i) const ;
```

Which is absolutely necessary to be able to allow statements like `x[0]`