# Operator overload in a templated method

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class (with irrelevant details stripped):

```
template <typename... Ts>
class ParameterPack
{
  private:
    std::tuple<Ts...> parameters;


  public:
    ParameterPack<Ts...>(const char* pVariableName)
    {
        /// Irrelevant extra details
    }


    template <typename T, std::size_t idx>
    T getValue()
    {
        return std::get<idx>(parameters);
    }


    template <std::size_t idx>
    void updateValue(unsigned int val)
    {
        std::get<idx>(parameters) = val;

        /// Irrelevant extra details
    }

template <class... Ts>
static ParameterPack<Ts...>* extractParameterPack(const char* name)
{
    // Construnt the new parameter extractor
    auto paramPack = new ParameterPack<Ts...>(name);

    /// Irrelevant extra details

    return paramPack;
}
};
```

Whose primary function is to parse a string into its data elements (held internally in a private tuple). I am trying to improve the ergonomics of the `updateValue` and `getValue` interface however.

I would like to overload `[]` to be to change the calling syntax from:

```
    auto val1 = parameterPack->getValue<float, 1>();
```

to:

```
    auto test2 = parameterPack[1];
```

But my overloads never take effect. I think the overload should look something close to:

or possibly:

```
    template <typename T, std::size_t idx>
    const T& operator[](std::size_t _idx) const
    {
        std::cout << "yay, overloading " << idx << std::endl;
        return idx * 1.0;
        // return std::get<idx>(parameters);
    }
```

If I call `operator[]` directly, it executes my overload, but not if I just try to use the `[]` operator normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to specialize a templated `operator[]` on the index, since the index is a run-time property.

For this reason `std::tuple` has a `get<idx>()` member function instead of `operator[]` (see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606464/why-can-we-not-access-elements-of-a-tuple-by-index)).

In addition, it's not possible to deduce a function (or operator) return type from an assignment.

So nether `T` nor `idx` in `template <typename T, std::size_t idx> operator[] ...` can be deduced, unfortunately, which excludes it from the set of viable overload candidates.